# R data.table, how to get complete dt, when using .SDcols

Tags: r, data.table

consider following dt:

```
dt <- data.table(id=c(rep(1,11),rep(2,10)),col1=c(100:80),col2=c(95:75),col3=c(2,100:81)) 
changeCols <- c("col1","col2","col3")
newCols <- paste0(changeCols, "_diff")
dt[, (newCols) := .SD - shift(.SD), by=id, .SDcols=changeCols][]
```

Now, I need to detect "jumps" on the second position (in that case remove the first position) in several columns, like it is the case in the **col3_diff**, I try do do it via:

```
dt[, if (.SD[2]>0) .SD[-1] else .SD, by=id, .SDcols=newCols]
```

I get only the subset of the data.table, i.e. I lose col1,col2, col3, but I need the complete dt.

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Not very clear. Are you try to use `(.SD[2]>0)`  to `detect "jumps" on the second position`?  First, you need to check the output of `dt[, .SD[2] , by=id, .SDcols=newCols] `. There is no problem that you only get the subset because `by=id, .SDcols=newCols` already deternine the output columns.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what I need is a data.table containing all features from the dt. When we check `dt[, .SD[2] , by=id, .SDcols=newCols]` we see col3_diff is >0, so the if case, applies, and this row needs to be deleted, while all colums from dt should remain.

Comment: Before you go any further, you need to address the fact that your code generates a warning: `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`. Warnings are there for a reason, in this case it tells you that you are using `if` improperly (perhaps `any` or `all`?).

Comment: right, I meant to have any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(data.table)
dt[, .SD[rowSums(!sapply(.SD[, newCols, with=FALSE],
                         function(z) z[2] < 0 | seq_along(z) != 1L)) == 0,],
   by = id]
#        id  col1  col2  col3 col1_diff col2_diff col3_diff
#     <num> <int> <int> <num>     <int>     <int>     <num>
#  1:     1    99    94   100        -1        -1        98
#  2:     1    98    93    99        -1        -1        -1
#  3:     1    97    92    98        -1        -1        -1
#  4:     1    96    91    97        -1        -1        -1
#  5:     1    95    90    96        -1        -1        -1
#  6:     1    94    89    95        -1        -1        -1
#  7:     1    93    88    94        -1        -1        -1
#  8:     1    92    87    93        -1        -1        -1
#  9:     1    91    86    92        -1        -1        -1
# 10:     1    90    85    91        -1        -1        -1
# 11:     2    89    84    90        NA        NA        NA
# 12:     2    88    83    89        -1        -1        -1
# 13:     2    87    82    88        -1        -1        -1
# 14:     2    86    81    87        -1        -1        -1
# 15:     2    85    80    86        -1        -1        -1
# 16:     2    84    79    85        -1        -1        -1
# 17:     2    83    78    84        -1        -1        -1
# 18:     2    82    77    83        -1        -1        -1
# 19:     2    81    76    82        -1        -1        -1
# 20:     2    80    75    81        -1        -1        -1
#        id  col1  col2  col3 col1_diff col2_diff col3_diff
```

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following -

```
library(data.table)
if(any(dt[2, ..newCols] > 0)) dt <- dt[-2]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I require the other "jumps",only the "jumps" on the second position needs to be deleted, as it couse some problems in the further analysis.

Comment: @Irina If there is a jump in second position do you want to delete the 2nd row or the 1st row? In your question you are deleting 1st row but in the comment you mention to delete 2nd row. I have edited the answer to delete 2nd row if you want to delete 1st row use `dt <- dt[-1]`.

Comment: Yes, sorry... in that case, I want to delete the first row. Thanks a lot! But I miss here the group by=id.